# C TCP socket can't recieve file

Tags: c, file, sockets, networking, tcp

I am trying to write a simple file transfer between sockets in C. My client code looks like this:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv){
    int sockfd, n;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;

    sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

    servaddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port=htons(22000);

    inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &(servaddr.sin_addr));

    connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen("text.txt", "r");
    sendfile(sockfd, fp, NULL, 100);
}
```

And my server code looks like this:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    int listen_fd, comm_fd;

    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;

    listen_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htons(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(22000);

    bind(listen_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

    listen(listen_fd, 10);

    comm_fd = accept(listen_fd, (struct sockaddr*) NULL, NULL);

    int bytes;
    char rec[100];

    FILE * fp;
    fp = fopen("random.txt", "w");

    while((bytes = read(comm_fd, rec, 100)) > 0){  
        fwrite(rec, 1, bytes, fp);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am sending `text.txt` file to server from client. Then on server, I try to read it and put the contents in `random.txt` in while loop but when I execute them, client finishes working, server doesn't stop working and nothing is written in `random.txt`.
Can you suggest why?

Comment: Check return codes.

Comment: Nice and clean error checking and logging through out the whole code, provides debugging for free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sendfile` expects a file descriptor as the second argument, not a `FILE *`. If you included all necessary header files in your code you would get the corresponding error messages during the compilation.

To get a file descriptor open the file with `open`, i.e. replace lines

```
FILE* fp;
fp = fopen("text.txt", "r");
```

with

```
int fp;
fp = open("text.txt", O_RDONLY);
```

Also, for a production version, do not forget to check for error return values of functions like `open`, `connect`, `bind`, ... and to close files and sockets when you do not use them anymore.

Comment: How can I take the file descriptor of file named `text.txt`

Comment: @GeorgeTsertsvadze you can use `fileno`.

Comment: Thanks.
I have more questions regarding sockets and files but StackOveflow doesn't let me ask another question for 90 mins. Is there a way of chat or something like that to ask you those questions?

Comment: @GeorgeTsertsvadze Just a friendly reminder: SO is not a private tutoring site. Askers are expected to do reasonable research on their own.